# How to store values from TextArea in a table in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

In a view, I have a DropDownList and a button and a TextArea.

When I click on the button, the selected value in the DropDownList is added to the TextArea.

**The values added are sperated by a space " " and that with using script.**

This is the code of the view :

```
<fieldset><legend>Gestion</legend>

        <div>
        <%:Html.Label("Fonction :")%>
        <%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedFonction",null, new{ id = "ff" })%></div>
        <br />
        <div><input type="button" value="Ajouter" id="aj"  onclick="addtext()"/></div>
        <br />
        <div>
        <textarea id="tt" cols="10"  name="S1" rows="8" readonly="true"></textarea>
        </div>
</fieldset>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var storedValues = [];
    function addtext() {

        var ff = document.getElementById('ff');
        var tt = document.getElementById('tt');


        var selectedValue = ff.options[ff.selectedIndex].value + " ";
        if (storedValues.indexOf(selectedValue) === -1) {
            storedValues.push(selectedValue)
            tt.value = storedValues.join('')
        }

    }
</script>
```

This is what i did in the controller :

```
Fonction_Poste FP = new Fonction_Poste();
            var value1 = Request["S1"];
            FP.ID_Fonction = value1;
```

This is code is only available when I entered **one value** in the TextArea.

When the user add many values, they are stored in the textarea sperated by a space between each others.

So I have to save them in a table, but i didn' t find how to elimnate the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some other delimiter like the ~ when you are using in javascript. like the one shown below

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var storedValues = [];
function addtext() {

    var ff = document.getElementById('ff');
    var tt = document.getElementById('tt');


    var selectedValue = ff.options[ff.selectedIndex].value + " ";
    if (storedValues.indexOf(selectedValue) === -1) {
        storedValues.push(selectedValue)
        tt.value = storedValues.join('~')
    }

}
```

In the model, you should then be having like this

```
public class Fonction_Poste {
public List<string> ID_Fonction {get;set;}

}
```

In the Action method, you can use like the following,

```
var value1 = Request["S1"];
FP.ID_Fonction = value1.contains('~')?value1.split('~').ToList():null;
```

Or else, you can create a javascript array and then push each item into the array and then post the data using JSON to the controller so that it will be automatically bound to the list by default model binding.

Choose the approach that suits your requirement. I would vote for the Javascript array based posting mechanism which will be easy to use and no need to join and split with special characters.

Comment: thx for the answer,,but I can't apply contains and split on a string value,,,an error appaer

Comment: Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'contains' and no extension method 'contains' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
Error 2 'string' does not contain a definition for 'split' and no extension method 'split' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

split it by spaces

```
var requireddata=listdata.split("");
```

it automatically store the data in a array